# How to let each user of web app use their own credentials to database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, servicestack

We're building an app where each user is required to have a personal login to database (logins are created by us), and I'm trying to find the best way to implement this.

So far the options are

- construct the connection string on the fly from user-provided username and password; however I'd like to have the ability to keep user logged in between sessions, and keeping username/password in a cookie doesn't seem like a good idea, even if cookie is encrypted.
- Use active directory. I'm exploring this option at the moment, but I'm using ServiceStack and don't see how to switch the user context - might just need to dig deeper.

Anyways, if there's a well-known way to implement this - I'd appreciate a nod in a right direction.

Comment: Why does each person need their own username for the database? You should just have a single db username for the application, then use AD to manage roles and privileges for the functionality in the application. Every record would have a "created by" and "updated by" column to track what user was associated to each record. You can also build in an audit trail, which is probably the reason behind the request for individual DB usernames.

Comment: We're implementing row-level security, so need to be able to identify specific users.

Comment: I get that you're looking for row-level security. I've always done this by tracking a userID on each row, along with managing roles and privileges (who can access or change data in what tables) via application code and user settings, not by swapping out connection strings based on the current user.

Comment: I'm trying to push security part completely to SQL Server side, without having to rely on the business logic to provide user id etc.

Comment: Did you find a solution?